# Code highlighting in ConTeXt

Tags: context, highlighting

What is the best way to highlight code when using ConTeXt? I am aware of support for specific languages, as described on the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text), but it seems rather limited at present. I know that we could also rely on vim, through the `t-vim` module.

Now, I wonder if there exists more automated ways to deal with other languages like R, Python, Lisp, Asymptote? Also, I would like to be able to combine verbatim and mathematical notations, as it is currently available in [Minted](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/), for example.

A working example would be very appreciated.

Comment: `t-vim` can deal with any language for which there is syntax highlighting support in vim.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, thanks. I like vim colors although I use Emacs :) In fact, I was rather looking for a 'pure' ConTeXt solution, in the spirit of the [minted](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) LaTeX package.

Comment: @chl: `minted` isn't a pure Latex solution, since it relies on Pygments, the Python syntax highlighter.

Comment: @Charles You're damned right! I guess I have to write custom pretty printer then?! I was hoping that something along Lua/MkIV already existed...

Comment: @chl: I've wondered about how tricky it would be to translate Pygments' Latex formatter into a Context formatter, and I think it would be easy.  You'd then have coverage of all the languages that Pygments covers.  Porting `listings`, which is pure Latex, I think would be hard.

Comment: MkIV has a new parser/pretty-printer. See the ConTeXt mailing list for a few discussions and look at `v-*.(mkiv|lua)` files for examples.

Comment: @Aditya Cool, thanks for this. I will look at ntg-context. If no answer comes within few days, I think you could simply drop this comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Custom_pretty_printer

Comment: @Aditya: Can you link to the discussion of this pretty-printer?

Comment: You can try using one of Pygments ImageFormatters through the filter module https://github.com/adityam/filter.

Comment: @Mica perhaps you could add an answer about the custom pretty printer so we can get this question off the "unanswered list"

Comment: Starting a bounty, with the hope of closing this question :-) /cc @Seamus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are willing to use an external tool, then `t-vim` provides highlighting  for **many** languages. You can use it as follows: define a typing

```
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping [RUBY]  [syntax=ruby]
```

and then use it either as an evnironment

```
    \startRUBY
      ...
    \stopRUBY
```

or inline

```
    \inlineRUBY{...}
```

This module does not support math escape, but with luatex, it is easy to support. Here is a complete example.

```
\newcatcodetable\minimalmathtable

\startcatcodetable \minimalmathtable
    \catcode\backslashasciicode  = \escapecatcode
    \catcode\leftbraceasciicode  = \begingroupcatcode  
    \catcode\rightbraceasciicode = \endgroupcatcode
    \catcode\endoflineasciicode  = \activecatcode
    \catcode\formfeedasciicode   = \activecatcode
    \catcode\spaceasciicode      = \activecatcode
    \catcode\dollarasciicode     = \mathshiftcatcode
\stopcatcodetable 

\unprotect
\starttexdefinition mathescaped #1
  \pushcatcodetable
  \setcatcodetable \minimalmathtable
  \ctxcommand{parsemath(\!!bs #1 \!!es)}
  \popcatcodetable
\stoptexdefinition
\protect

\startluacode
  local function unescape(content)
      local s = string.gsub(content, '\\\\', '\\')
      s = string.gsub(s, '\\{', '{')
      s = string.gsub(s, '\\}', '}')
      return s
  end

  local dollar = lpeg.P("$")
  local nodollar = (1 - dollar)
  local math = lpeg.Cs(dollar * nodollar^0 * dollar) / unescape
  local any = lpeg.P(1)
  local match = lpeg.Cs( (math + any)^0 )

  function commands.parsemath(content)
    local s = lpeg.match(match, content)
    tex.sprint(s)
  end

\stopluacode

\usemodule[vim]

\startcolorscheme[pscolor]
    \definesyntaxgroup 
        [Comment]
        [command=\mathescaped]
\stopcolorscheme

\definevimtyping[python][syntax=python]

\starttext

\startpython
# Returns $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$
def sum_upto(n)
    r = range(1, n+1)
    return sum(r)
\stoppython

\stoptext
```

The same restrictions as the listings package apply, i.e., spaces are active, so you should avoid spaces in math mode.

**EDIT**: The new (2012.12.17) version of `t-vim` module supports math escape in the `Comment` region. To active it you need to pass `escape=on` to `\definevimtyping` and use `\m{...}` or `\math{...}` for math mode. Thus, instead of the above kludge, you can use

```
\definevimtyping[python][syntax=python, escape=on]

\startpython
# Returns \m{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i}
def sum_upto(n)
    r = range(1, n+1)
    return sum(r)
\stoppython
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the working example about math support. It looks great. I'll try this ASAP.

Comment: Just tried it, but cannot get it to work. I encountered errors with Module Catcodes (`! Undefined control sequence.  <argument> \catcode \tabasciicode`) when trying to compile a working example (the above one, or any of those available in your Github repos using `context`). I don't know why because I succeeded in compiling some files in the past... I shall return to this later.

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old version of ConTeXt. I think that `\tabsciicode` etc were introduced around April 2011.

Comment: Yes, that's what I realized afterwards (I have the minimals beta version on my other computer, but I tested your example on TeXLive 2010 :-) Everything works fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to use `Pygments` similar to what `minted` does?

Comment: Not out of the box. I had looked into `pygments` when initially writing `t-vim`, but could not find any documentation on what the different codes mean. If you understand the output of pygments (or are willing to spend the time to learn it), then it should be a relatively easy thing to support it as part of the `t-vim` module.

Comment: Also see https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/clean-tex-output/ for other syntax highlighters that I tested.