# ConTeXt: Syntax highlighting of source code within XHTML documents

Tags: context, sourcecode, syntax-highlighting

## Background

Looking to apply syntax highlighting to source code snippets embedded within XHTML `code` elements, demarcated with a `class` attribute to indicate the language.

Using:

```
mtx-context     | current version: 2021.11.30 19:49
```

**Note:** The XHTML is produced from a Markdown document, such as:

````
Here is an XML snippet:

``` xml
<import src="constants.xml" />
<device type="web" uri="HOST">
  <form ... />
</device>
```

Here is a Java snippet:

``` java
import java.net.*;

public class JavaClass {
  // ...
}
```
````

## Problem

There are a couple of issues:

- Calling `\xmlflushspacewise{#1}` does not seem to afford the ability to apply syntax highlighting to the nested source code snippet.
- Applying syntax highlighting dynamically based on the `code` element's `class`, which follows the form "language-X" where X could be any well-known programming language (`xml`, `python`, `java`, `ruby`, `javascript`, and others).

## Code

The following example typesets the source code snippet as expected:

```tex
\startbuffer[html]
<html>
<body>
<pre>
      <code class="language-xml">&lt;import src="constants.xml" /&gt;
&lt;import src="tests/login.xml" /&gt;

&lt;device type="web" uri="HOST"&gt;
  &lt;click id="device" /&gt;

  &lt;form id="upload-file"&gt;
    &lt;assign id="firmware" value="FILENAME.fw" /&gt;
    &lt;click id="upload-file-button" /&gt;
  &lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/device&gt;
</code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{html|body|pre|code}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\startxmlsetups xml:html
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:pre
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:code
  \xmlflushspacewise{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{html}{}
```

This produces:

[image: XML document output]

## Question

How would you apply syntax highlighting to the output in a way that is agnostic with respect to the code snippet language being coloured?

As a bonus, is it possible to do in a cross-platform way (that is, not relying on vim)?

## Related

- [Code highlighting in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7789/2148)

Comment: I understand the desire not to rely on vim, but would just point out that the t-vim module is cross platform.

Comment: Right. It's cross-platform, but `vim` must be installed on all platforms and, presumably, its executable directory added to the PATH. Installation a bit painful on Windows, especially if you need to get IT's permission to install executables (self-contained versions notwithstanding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly copied from the [Wiki page "Verbatim XML"](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_XML):

```tex
\startbuffer[html]
<html>
<body>
<pre>
      <code class="language-xml">&lt;import src="constants.xml" /&gt;
&lt;import src="tests/login.xml" /&gt;

&lt;device type="web" uri="HOST"&gt;
  &lt;click id="device" /&gt;

  &lt;form id="upload-file"&gt;
    &lt;assign id="firmware" value="FILENAME.fw" /&gt;
    &lt;click id="upload-file-button" /&gt;
  &lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/device&gt;
</code>
    </pre>

    <pre>
Hello!
    </pre>

    <pre>
    <code class="language-lua">
for k, v in ipairs(table) do
    print(k, v)
end
    </code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{html|body|pre|code}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\startxmlsetups xml:html
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\usemodule[scite] % Optional

\startluacode
  function xml.functions.highlight( t )
    local lang = (xml.attribute( t, "/", "class" ) or "")
      :match("language%-(.*)")
    local options = "before=\\startlinenumbering,after=\\stoplinenumbering"

    if lang then
      options = options .. ",option=" .. lang
    end

    buffers.assign(
      "highlight",
      "\\starttyping[" ..
      options ..
      "]\n" ..
      xml.textonly( t ) ..
      "\n\\stoptyping"
    )
    context.getbuffer { "highlight" }
  end
\stopluacode

\startxmlsetups xml:pre
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:code
  \pushcatcodetable
  \setcatcodetable\ctxcatcodes
  \startnarrower[left]
      \xmlfunction{#1}{highlight}
  \stopnarrower
  \popcatcodetable
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{html}{}
```

> As a bonus, is it possible to do in a cross-platform way (that is, not relying on vim)?

You can use the [builtin highlighters to highlight XML, MetaPost, TeX, Lua, and C](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text#Included_Formatters). You can also use the builtin `scite` module which [supports XML, MetaPost, TeX, Lua, C, C++, SQL, and JSON](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/modules/mkiv/m-scite.mkiv?search=definetyping).

If you need more languages, you can code your own highlighters (not *too* difficult) or use the [`vim` module](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/dev/vim-README.md).

Comment: FWIW, I looked into adding my own highlighter for Java and it was confusing right out of the gate. For example, C++ has two syntax files in different locations with no immediate indication as to which one is needed. What would be helpful is a full and complete step-by-step guide that describes how to add a simple C-family syntax highlighter to scite. Another example, it isn't obvious how to "debug" problems with the highlighter---like how do you output a simple logging statement into ConTeXt's logger? It may be a bit misleading to state that it's "not too difficult". I eventually gave up.